# extjs4 - changing the default id/text fields in a Tree Panel / Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

The extjs 4 tree panel uses the record properties id & text by default for the nodes of the tree.

Is there any way to change it to some different property names?

There's a way to specify the root element but I can't see any config setting for those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the displayField config for treePanel, in the extjs api they say it;s a boolean value with default value text... That's just wrong :P, actualy you can put something like displayField: 'name' and it will show the name field from the store. But i don't think you can change the id property.

If you want to change the id property you can use the mapping config on the model fields and let the treePanel configs as they are. something like

```
fields : [ 
        { name: 'id', type:'int',mapping: 'yourId'},
        { name: 'text', type: 'string', mapping: 'yourText'}
    ]
```

**Edit** As Ben suggested you can change the property names of a tree panel by using the `displayField` config for the tree panel and the `idProperty` for the model of the treeStore.

Comment: aah, very nice. didn't know about that mapping property - that actually answer a separate question I was wondering about how to do :)

Comment: I was looking at the Tree source code and I think the id could be overwritten by setting the idProperty config on the model itself.. haven't tried it though

Comment: @nscrob Thanks, fixed up the docs for the next release re: displayField.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm. Setting idProperty on the model and displayField on the tree solves the problem and doesn't require the mapped fields. Good to know

Comment: @nscrob. Maybe edit your answer and add that as a footnote for those who come find this answer later